# Replace bytes in a file at specific index with specific length

Tags: android, io, inputstream

In my app, I receive some files. At the beginning I just have the size of this file. So I create an empty file (filled of 0). After creating this file, I will receive 1024 bytes per seconds. Thoses bytes chunks correspond to file parts.

So I need to replace the current content of the file by the bytes I'm receiving.

This means I have to read/write the file every seconds. For small files, it's not a problem, but sometimes I'm having big files (>2Mo).

I searched but I couldn't find a way to replace a part of file at a given index without reading and reaching the while file everytime. Is there any simple solution and performance friendly?

Comment: RandomAccessFile?

Comment: Yes.... I was just about to blow because I tried everything with FileChannel, OuputStream... And after posting here, I found RandomAccessFile... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After trying so much things with OuputStream, FileChannel, etc... and post this question. I finally found the "RandomAccessFile" class that solves my problem.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html